# Ember.js trouble with select and radiobutton bindings example

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm new with Ember and have a big troubles with basics. Can you answer on two questions:

1. There are two users, next to the name of each there is a link "Edit" which opens an edit form. In the form there are text inputs and SELECT with the names of cities. If I choose to edit the item in the entire form perfectly substituted data and shows the current city in SELECT. But when I then click on the editing of another item SELECT remains with the previous city(
   I think this is something about bindings. This is my jsbin http://jsbin.com/bidoma/8/
2. How did add/edit form with radio buttons? Do you have working jsbin examples?

Waiting for an answer :)

**UPD**: Comment to first question. The question is how to update the selection when the edited object has been changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was easy. To get object instead of promise needed write **content** in the end of the my selection value.
It should be

```
selection=model.city.content
```

instead

```
selection=model.city
```